# How to predict result using existing results

Tags: c#, tensorflow, prediction

I have a data of results of games played on every day as in the below screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Each row represents each day and each column represents each game.

`1` means win and `0` represents loss.

Using the available results, I have to predict the results of future games.

I have searched the internet and have found some techniques like [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), but I have no idea how to use these.

I have to use the C# language for this. Does anyone know any techniques that I can use for the given data?

Comment: Tensorflow or AI/ ML in general are absolute overkill for this. What you want is see how well the player is doing, and calculate the probability that he'll win. For example if the player won 9/10 games in the past there's a quite high likelihood of him winning again. I'm no mathematician, so don't quote me on this

Comment: You can use Microsoft's Machine Learning package for .NET (ML.NET). Here is an example on how to predict taxi fares:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/taxi-fare